# How To Import and Display Excel (.xlsx) File to Blazor WASM Client Side (Without Uploading to Server)

Tags: c#, .net-5, blazor-webassembly, npoi, closedxml

Like the title says. Lots of examples online for uploading files to backend but I'm after verification client side/offline followed by an upload of data only (no files). In theory, anything that runs on .Net5 should be able to run in WASM at a close performance. I'm trying to unload those hefty operations to clients' machines.

I've had some success with ClosedXML but when the file is a few 1000 rows it becomes incredibly slow. Using ClosedXML in Blazor Server-Side loads 100,000's rows with ease.

Notes:

- Using MudBlazor UI Components
- I have a stream from file instead of a file path for ClosedXML (like I would on a console app), I think this is the only way in WASM but I may be wrong.
- I've ran the same in NPOI with similar results (slow in WASM, fast in Server Side).
- I'd prefer to avoid EPPlus unless it has a magical fix.

Page:

```
@page "/upload"
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>Upload Data</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates uploading data from Excel.</p>

<InputFile id="fileInput" OnChange="UploadFiles" hidden single />

<MudButton HtmlTag="label"
           Variant="Variant.Filled"
           Color="Color.Primary"
           StartIcon="@Icons.Filled.CloudUpload"
           for="fileInput">
    Upload Files
</MudButton>

@if (dataTable == null)
{
    <p><em>Please upload Excel File</em></p>
}
else
{
    <MudTable Items="@dataTable.AsEnumerable().Take(500)" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" T="DataRow" RowsPerPage="100">
        <HeaderContent>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
            {
                <MudTh>@col.ColumnName</MudTh>
            }
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
            @foreach (var cell in context.ItemArray)
            {
                <MudTd>@cell.ToString()</MudTd>
            }
        </RowTemplate>
    </MudTable>
}

@code {
    //private IList<IBrowserFile> files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
    private DataTable dataTable;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    }

    private async Task UploadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        dataTable = await ExcelHelper.GetDataTableFromExcel(e.File);
    }
}
```

Function:

```
public static async Task<DataTable> GetDataTableFromExcel(IBrowserFile file)
        {
            DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();

            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.OpenReadStream(file.Size).CopyToAsync(memStream);
                using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(memStream, XLEventTracking.Disabled))
                {
                    //Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
                    IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

                    //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
                    bool firstRow = true;
                    foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
                    {
                        //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                        if (firstRow)
                        {
                            foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                            {
                                dtTable.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                            }
                            firstRow = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Add rows to DataTable.
                            dtTable.Rows.Add();
                            int i = 0;

                            foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(row.FirstCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber, row.LastCellUsed().Address.ColumnNumber))
                            {
                                dtTable.Rows[dtTable.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return dtTable;
        }
```

The line causing the delay is:

```
using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(memStream, XLEventTracking.Disabled))
```

I need help fixing the slow reading of the xlsx file, or a completely different approach if there's a better way! A better way achieving this goal, no cheating/uploading files to the server :)

Comment: Try EPPlus or work directly with the OpenXML library. (ClosedXML and EPPlus are OpenXML wrapper libraries)

Comment: @FrancoisBotha thank you. Good points. I should mention that I'm after an open source solution. I tried NPOI with similar results. Running the exact same function on Blazor server side is really fast so it has to be a WebAssembly workaround, or we've hit the limit.

Comment: EPPlus was fully open-source until a certain version. Can't remember the exact version when that changed. Working directly with OpenXML is also a fully open-source solution, just more difficult. Disclaimer: I'm the ClosedXML maintainer and I don't think it will be a viable solution for your use-case.

Comment: You are a legend. ClosedXML has helped me a lot in my fun projects. I'm currently getting this work done on server-side Blazor and it's working well. Maybe WASM needs an approach that always stays within its RAM restrictions. Still worth keeping this out there with fingers crossed.